# Looping in R Program

Tags: r, loops, data-extraction

I have a data set of 5 columns and some 18,000,000 rows. I need to segregate the data based on the values in column 1, the values in column 1 are numbers from 1 to 1000, and they get repeated a certain number of times exclusive of each other. How do I segregate the data using a for loop, to create nX5 arrays for each number in Column 1, i.e if 1 comes for 60 times, I should have a matrix of 60X5. It should look for that number and separate all such instances in a loop. I have been trying

```
for (i in 1:2) A[i] <- Data[ which(Data$Column=='i')]
```

but nothing happened. [A] vector remains null and I am not able to extract data.

Comment: `Data$Column=='i'` checks for literal 'i' not value of variable i.

Comment: If you have such a big number of data rows, try using `data.table` .http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu/files/tutorial_Matt.pdf

Comment: @Deena, that's an age old link. See the [data.table project page wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) on github instead.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having such big data frame, I'd highly recommend using data.table . (Links attached in the comments).

Anyway, the following might give you some insight:

```
seg.ID = unique(Data[,1])
results = list()

for (ID in seg.ID) 
{
 results[[ID]] = Data[Data[,1] == ID,  ]
}

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using split function.Suppose the data frame is as shown:

```
> df
   speed dist
1      4    2
2      4   10
3      7    4
4      7   22
5      8   16
6      9   10
7     10   18
8     10   26
9     10   34
10    11   17
```

You can use split function to split the data frame into list of data frames.

```
> split(df,df$speed)
$`4`
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10

$`7`
  speed dist
3     7    4
4     7   22

$`8`
  speed dist
5     8   16

$`9`
  speed dist
6     9   10

$`10`
  speed dist
7    10   18
8    10   26
9    10   34

$`11`
   speed dist
10    11   17
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Read more about split function here http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/split.html